# Image Overlay on video using JavaCV for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv, iplimage

I'm trying to add image with transparent background on the video, using JavaCV.

I'm using FFmpegFrameGrapper, for grapping frames and I'm trying to set my image on every frame of the video, and record it again using FFmpeg Recorder, but no result.

I'm doing something like this

// img is the IplImage of a frame

```
private IplImage setOverlay(IplImage img){
    cvCopy(overlayImage, img); //overlayImage I'm getting from 
                               //internal storage
    cvResetImageROI(img);

    return img;
}
```

Comment: @TalhaQamar check it ))

Comment: Did you manage to overlay an image? I have a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479205/javacv-android-strange-colors-on-overlay-while-streaming-to-rtmp-server Could you please take a look at it?